# ASP.NET Core 3.1 How to force view to reload when clicking browser back button

Tags: asp.net-core, browser-cache, asp.net-core-3.1

```
 [ResponseCache(Location = ResponseCacheLocation.None, NoStore = true)]
 public IActionResult Index()
 { ...}
```

Is there an easy to way to force when Index view is accessed to avoid loading cached data. I have a final page (view) and when it is complete and if the user clicks back browser button I want to force action View to be executed. Using asp.net Core 3.1. When testing. when user clicks back browser button the action index never gets executed.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to check `PerformanceNavigationTiming.type`,If the type is `back_forward`,it means the page was accessed by navigating into the history. Here is a demo:

js:

```
$(function () {
            var perfEntries = performance.getEntriesByType("navigation");
            if (perfEntries[0].type == "back_forward") {
                location.reload(true);
            }
        })
```

result(I click back browser button,and you can see the Index action is called twice,and I'm using chrome):
[image]

Comment: This is [deprecated](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/PerformanceNavigation)

Comment: I have updated my answer,you can use `PerformanceNavigationTiming.type`.